# AdMob EU Consent SDK iOS Error: consent form can be used with custom provider selection only

Tags: ios, swift, admob

When I request the form for the EU Consent I am retrieving an error regarding the ads providers list, in the documentation says pick 12 manually in AdMob, which I already have done, explained in [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/eu-consent#tips_for_using_the_consent_sdk)

When I load the form in the app I am getting this error

```
    (lldb) po error.localizedDescription
"Error: consent form can be used with custom provider selection only."
```

And If I check the ads provider array it has 200 entrances no 12... weird because I have double checked the AdMob config and is right...

Anyone having the same problem?

Thanks :)

Comment: Fixed: the AdMob account took 4 days to get verified....